# How to right-align text in a div with text-align "justify"

Tags: css

I'd like the last sentence of my text to be right-aligned (the rest of the text is justified).

I tried the `<span>` below in the middle of a `<p>` tag but without success:

```css
span.activity-conclusion
{
    font:22px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:200;
    text-align:right;
    color:#467FD9;
}
```

And that's the CSS code of the `<div>` where the text is:

```css
#activity-right { 
    font:12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-top:20px;
    height: 100%;
    color:#000;
    width: 60%; 
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    text-align:justify;
    border-left: 1px dotted #666;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #c4c8cc;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #c4c8cc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an id to the `<p>` that you want to affect and use text-align: right;

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean something like p.activity{ ? Then how to do I reflect that in the html code? Tks

Answer (score 2):

```css
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: right;
```

[`text-align-last`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align-last) is part of CSS3, and works in Firefox and IE... unfortunately, not yet in WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

Give `dir` attribute to the `p` tag and give the value `rtl`

Eg:

```
<p dir="rtl"> Your text here </p>
```

Check a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/ALaVv/1/